# What does the Namekian password for the Dragon Balls translate to?

Tags: dragon-ball

In the Namek Saga, we found out that the Namekian Dragon Balls need a password to be activated, which Dende uses on behalf of the Z Warriors. Since he says it in Namekian, I am wondering if there is a translation of what he is saying?

Comment: i bet it's the same as for shenglong :D

Comment: @Mintri funny you should mention that because i thought up this question when i was thinking why shenglong has no password or if the invocation for shenglong was a password

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is no known explanation for the password in manga AFAIK. According to the Dragon Ball Wikia, only a few words of the Namekian language are explained. Piccolo and Porunga are the two words really explained and the others are in filler episodes.

**The password is "Takkaraput pop porunga pupiritt paro!" . As far as you make it out, Porunga is part of the password. And the episode is named as "Password is Porunga". So the best guess is something like calling Porunga. Also for Shenron, replace Porunga with Shenron in the password. So the password isn't a randomn mystery but some sort of calling to the dragon's name. It is however a guess as there is no official translation**.

To quote the wikia on this:

> The Namekian language is a fictional language spoken by Namekians,  individuals native to Planet Namek. "Piccolo" and "Porunga" have been defined in the Dragon Ball manga; other words appear as filler material in episodes of Dragon Ball Z. In Dragon Ball, Piccolo and Kami speak in Namekian language to each other during the 23rd World Martial Arts Tournament; although their actual words are translated, Namekian letters appear on the screen.

Here is a list of known Namekian words, some translated:

> - ***"Avishta"*** – never explained, although it may have some relation to *'hello'*, as Krillin says this during the Namek greeting gesture he  makes to Raiti.
> - ***"Butla antu"*** – *"bed"*, literally *"sleepy time"*
> - ***"Dablirobe"*** – never explained
> - ***"Dorigelop crafca"*** – *''fly to''*
> - ***"Onska ropeca"*** – never explained, although it has some relation to *'turn around'*, as the phrase causes the Namek spaceship to turn while in flight.
> - ***"Piccolo"*** – *"from another world"* or *"open"*
> - ***"Porunga"*** – *"dragon of dreams"* or *"dragon of law"*
> - ***"Seata belta"*** – "toilet"
> - ***"Stando boomsca"*** – never explained, although it has some relation to *'fire'*, as the phrase activates the Namek spaceship's beam cannon.

According to Naroka's Namek to English translator, these are the remaining words that have been translated from Namek to English in the whole manga
"

> - ***"Stando boomsca"*** – Relation to *'blast'* or *'fire'*
> - ***"Pikonatto"*** – *"good day"*
> - ***"Kistan"*** - *"Guardian" *
> - ***"Dimo"*** - *"I'm"* or *"I am" *
> - ***"Matto espen"*** - *"What is your name" *
> - ***"Kado"*** - *"Hey"*
> - ***"Ba soun"*** - *"Over there"*
> - ***"Ne sinti"*** - Phrase, *"He/She seems well/nice"*
> - ***"Sinti"*** - *"Nice/Well"*
> - ***"Kabo ko"*** - *"Still"*
> - ***"Bäsa"*** - *"Unsure"*
> - ***"Horou"*** - *"Do you"*
> - ***"Sä"*** - *"It/It's"*
> - ***"Irra Pokabo"*** - *"Possible"*
> - ***"Kogata ro sa shikohama"*** - *"Do it or die"*

As you can see, the Namekian password has never been translated in the manga too.

Source: http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Namekian_language

http://wodsouls.freeforums.net/thread/1299/naroka-ukares-namekian-english-dictionary